# Symfony2/Doctrine error when submitting a form [new out of memory error]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been battling with this small learning project for a few days now.  It's a DVD title logging database interface.  There are two entities, Users and Titles.  I want to be able to save/retrieve to the database the ID of the user that made the title entry.

Here's the entities association details:

```
class Titles
{
   //...

   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="titles")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
   protected $addedBy;

 //...
}

class Users
{
   //...
   /**
   *
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Titles", mappedBy="addedBy")
   */
   protected $titles = array();


   //...
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to submit the form:

```
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, 
integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine
\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 1389
```

Here is the formBuilder method:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('genre');
}
```

and the addAction method:

```
public function addAction()
{
    // add title to db
    $title = new Titles();
    $form = $this->createForm(new TitlesType(), $title);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // persist to db
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager();
        $em->persist($title);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dvdLoggerdvdBundle_homepage'));
    }

    return $this->render('dvdLoggerdvdBundle:Page:add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Any tips regarding how to debug would be appreciated.  I'm still getting used to Symfony.

**update 1**

the whole titles entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Repository\loggerRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="titles")
 */
class Titles
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $genre;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 */
protected $dateAdded;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="titles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $addedBy;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->user_id = null; // Default value for column user_id
    $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->dateAdded = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $this->addedBy = 1;

}


/**
 * Set genre
 *
 * @param string $genre
 * @return Titles
 */
public function setGenre($genre)
{
    $this->genre = $genre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get genre
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGenre()
{
    return $this->genre;
}

/**
 * Set dateAdded
 *
 * @param string $dateAdded
 * @return Titles
 */
public function setDateAdded($dateAdded)
{
    $this->dateAdded = $dateAdded;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateAdded
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDateAdded()
{
    return $this->dateAdded;
}

/**
 * Set addedBy
 *
 * @param integer $addedBy
 * @return Titles
 */
public function setAddedBy($addedBy)
{
    $this->addedBy = $addedBy;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get addedBy
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getAddedBy()
{
    return $this->addedBy;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return Titles
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}
}
```

and the users entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Repository\usersRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class Users
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $rank;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $lastLogged;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Titles", mappedBy="addedBy")
 */
protected $titles = array();


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->titles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add titles
 *
 * @param \dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Titles $titles
 * @return Users
 */
public function addTitle(\dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Titles $titles)
{
    $this->titles[] = $titles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove titles
 *
 * @param \dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Titles $titles
 */
public function removeTitle(\dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Titles $titles)
{
    $this->titles->removeElement($titles);
}

/**
 * Get titles
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTitles()
{
    return $this->titles;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return Users
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set rank
 *
 * @param integer $rank
 * @return Users
 */
public function setRank($rank)
{
    $this->rank = $rank;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get rank
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getRank()
{
    return $this->rank;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return Users
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set lastLogged
 *
 * @param \DateTime $lastLogged
 * @return Users
 */
public function setLastLogged($lastLogged)
{
    $this->lastLogged = $lastLogged;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lastLogged
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getLastLogged()
{
    return $this->lastLogged;
}
}
```

Stack Trace

```
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php at line 1389  +
at ErrorHandler ->handle ('2', 'spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php', '1389', array('entity' => '1', 'assume' => '2'))
at spl_object_hash ('1')
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php at line 1389  +
at UnitOfWork ->getEntityState ('1', '2')
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php at line 788  +
at UnitOfWork ->computeAssociationChanges (array('fieldName' => 'addedBy', 'joinColumns' => array(array('name' => 'user_id', 'unique' => false, 'nullable' => true, 'onDelete' => null, 'columnDefinition' => null, 'referencedColumnName' => 'id')), 'cascade' => array(), 'inversedBy' => 'titles', 'targetEntity' => 'dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Users', 'fetch' => '2', 'type' => '2', 'mappedBy' => null, 'isOwningSide' => true, 'sourceEntity' => 'dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Titles', 'isCascadeRemove' => false, 'isCascadePersist' => false, 'isCascadeRefresh' => false, 'isCascadeMerge' => false, 'isCascadeDetach' => false, 'sourceToTargetKeyColumns' => array('user_id' => 'id'), 'joinColumnFieldNames' => array('user_id' => 'user_id'), 'targetToSourceKeyColumns' => array('id' => 'user_id'), 'orphanRemoval' => false), '1')
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php at line 687  +
at UnitOfWork ->computeChangeSet (object(ClassMetadata), object(Titles))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php at line 404  +
at UnitOfWork ->computeScheduleInsertsChangeSets ()
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php at line 711  +
at UnitOfWork ->computeChangeSets ()
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php at line 297  +
at UnitOfWork ->commit (null)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php at line 389  +
at EntityManager ->flush ()
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\src\dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Controller\PageController.php at line 48  +
at PageController ->addAction ()
at call_user_func_array (array(object(PageController), 'addAction'), array())
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2969  +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2931  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 3080  +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2330  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\web\app_dev.php at line 28  +
```

**update 2**

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager();

    $titles = $em->getRepository('dvdLoggerdvdBundle:Titles')->getAllTitles();


    return $this->render('dvdLoggerdvdBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
        'titles' => $titles

    ));
}
```

then the getAllTitles from the repo

```
public function getAllTitles()
{
    // view all records in db
    $titles = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t, u')
        ->leftJoin('t.addedBy', 'u')
        ->addOrderBy('t.title', 'DESC');

    return $titles->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Im presuming this is the issue, its sucking massive memory when querying the dbase, but I cant see why

Comment: Looks like you're trying to set an `integer` in a place of an `object`. Please post the rest of the code in your entities and also the stack trace for that warning.

Comment: will do right away. many thanks

Comment: I think the problem comes from your `Titles` entity. The `addedBy` field shoud be an object (`Users`) but you're giving `'1'` which is not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line completely from you `__construct()` method in `Title` entity.

```
$this->addedBy = 1;
```

And do this in your `PageController`.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$title->setAddedBy($this->getUser());
$em->persist($title);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: awesome.  thanks for that Stiven.  Ive substituted `$this->getUser()` with a find for the current user based on who is current logged in and it works lovely.

Comment: although it now wont display the listing page. I just get a white screen.  Ill try to figure that out next.  I do wonder if its easier to roll your own framework sometimes!!

Comment: yes.  the log is producing an out of memory error for some reason.  My indexAction method is very simple, Ill add it.

Comment: If you use Chrome, you can visit the page and with developers tools you can go to the Network tab, go to Preview and it will show you the error. It looks OK from your code. Maybe you should tweak `php.ini` a bit if it is an out of memory problem. I usually leave it at 128 MB

Comment: the memory log message is:  emergency.EMERGENCY: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 123469824 bytes), which is huge so Im assuming I have something mega wrong somewhere?

Comment: Ive put in the getAllTitles method

Comment: maybe Id better create a new question?

Comment: created a new question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228901/symfony2-doctrine2-excessive-memory-usage-while-running-query