# Symfony2/Doctrine2 excessive memory usage while running query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is a separate issue that has developed from [this question thread][1]

while loading a simple page displaying a table of data (only 2 object entries) I'm getting a memory emergency error.  Can anyone please tell me why?

here's the controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager();

    $titles = $em->getRepository('dvdLoggerdvdBundle:Titles')->getAllTitles();


    return $this->render('dvdLoggerdvdBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
        'titles' => $titles

    ));
}
```

then the getAllTitles from the repo

```
public function getAllTitles()
{
    // view all records in db
    $titles = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t, u')
        ->leftJoin('t.addedBy', 'u')
        ->addOrderBy('t.title', 'DESC');

    return $titles->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

the logfile is producing the following:

```
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] request.INFO: Matched route "dvdLoggerdvdBundle_homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Controller\PageController::indexAction", "_route": "dvdLoggerdvdBundle_homepage") [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 10 near 'u FROM dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Titles': Error: 'u' is not defined." at C:\xampp\htdocs\dvdLogger\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php line 63 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 10 near 'u FROM dvdLogger\\dvdBundle\\Entity\\Titles': Error: 'u' is not defined. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dvdLogger\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException.php:63, Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException: SELECT t, u FROM dvdLogger\\dvdBundle\\Entity\\Titles t ORDER BY t.title DESC at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dvdLogger\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException.php:41)"} []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.exception". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt" (parameters: "_controller": "web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction", "token": "b14d03", "_route": "_wdt") [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:50] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] request.INFO: Matched route "dvdLoggerdvdBundle_homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Controller\PageController::indexAction", "_route": "dvdLoggerdvdBundle_homepage") [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2014-08-10 14:49:59] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0_.id AS id0, t0_.title AS title1, t0_.genre AS genre2, t0_.dateAdded AS dateAdded3, t0_.user_id AS user_id4 FROM titles t0_ ORDER BY t0_.title DESC [] []
[2014-08-10 14:50:10] emergency.EMERGENCY: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 123469824 bytes) {"type":1,"file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dvdLogger\\vendor\\twig\\twig\\lib\\Twig\\Extension\\Debug.php","line":66} []
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this function? All Titles of ALL users or All Titles of a specific user?

Comment: The exception seems to indicate that you still don't have the mappings correct.  If you drop the left join stuff does it work?

Comment: And where is exactly is the "memory emergency error"?  Unless you have a zillion titles then you should not be getting any memory errors.  Might try passing an empty $titles = array() to your render function.  Maybe you have an infinite loop in your template.  Or have you installed a custom exception listener?  You should just be getting a simple exception query message especially if you are running in development mode.  Make sure you clear your logs after every request.

Comment: thanks for all the input.   Id like to display (for the time being at least) all the titles and the user who inputted them.  The memory leak was being caused by a `{{ dump(title) }}` call in the template oddly.  Ive taken that out and it runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show all the titles listed, you don't need a custom function, you can do something like this in you controller :

```
$titles = $em->getRepository('dvdLoggerdvdBundle:Titles')->findAll();
```

If you want to display all the titles the logged in user has added then do this:

```
$uid = $this->getUser()->getId();
$titles = $em->getRepository('dvdLoggerdvdBundle:Titles')->findBy(array('user_id'=>$uid));
```

I used the names you have shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227451/symfony2-doctrine-error-when-submitting-a-form-new-out-of-memory-error).

Alternative, suggestion, if you want to list sorted titles added by the logged in user, you can do this:

```
 public function getTitlesOfUser($userId) {
      return $this->createQueryBuilder('title')
                  ->where('title.user_id = :uid')
                  ->orderBy('title.title','DESC')
                  ->setParameter('uid', $userId)
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();
 }
 //or
 public function getTitlesOfUser($userObject) {
      return $this->createQueryBuilder('title')
                  ->where('title.addedBy = :user')
                  ->orderBy('title.title','DESC')
                  ->setParameter('user', $userObject)
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();
 }
```

Comment: He is trying to show a list of titles along with who added them.  The addedBy property references a user object.

Comment: That is why I have listed both ways, because his repository functions says in the comment : `// view all records in db`. Also, he has named his `joinColumn` as `user_id` thus the second method I have included.

Comment: Hmmm.  The view all records comment means that he want to see titles with the user who added them.  You first method would work but would require lazy loading of the user.  His query would avoid that.  The user_id refers to the database table column name not the title entity property name.  Your second method will not work.  You would need to use the actual user object.

Comment: We are getting a bit off topic here since he is not trying to find titles for a given user.  I think you were updating your answer while I was typing my comment.  The findBy('user_id'... is not going to work.  Your query builder stuff looks good.

Comment: I have an active project in Symfony2 2.3.18 and use the `findBy(array $options)` method and works fine. Now you made me curios if that is a wrong approach, or if it is not supposed to work, why it does in my case.

Comment: findBy works great but you would pass it array('addedBy' => $user)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59048/discussion-between-stiven-llupa-and-cerad).

Answer (score 0):

ok the memory leak was being caused by a `{{ dump(titles) }}` in the template.  I have no idea why it would do that as it was working before the join was added to pull the user.

Ive also managed to display the username using my first query above by accessing it with `{{ title.addedBy.username }}`

thanks for all the help, its been a steep learning curve!

I will though use the other query suggestion for loading titles from a specific user, so thank you for that.